# eBay API: Get all items currently in auction

Tags: bigdata, ebay-api

For an university project (Big Data lecture), I’d like to analyze auctions on eBay. I wasn’t able to find reliable information so far whether it’s possible to get all current auctions on eBay via their API or not. I only need the auction title and the current price and I am aware that this is a huge load of data, but I’m just curios.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible, in part because of the huge amount of data, and perhaps also because I don't think eBay wants people downloading data en masse like that. Doing so might allow people to do data mining and market research from a vantage point that is too publicly revealing for them.

If you're willing to settle for a large segment of data, look into eBay's Large Merchant Services and [their LMS API](https://go.developer.ebay.com/developers/ebay/products/large-merchant-services).

For your research project, you should be able to make sense of an even smaller subset of data by just pulling from eBay's Finding API in a few automated large chunks.